# Jersey: Couldn't find grammar element for class

Tags: java, rest, grails, jersey, jax-rs

I use Grails with the [JaxRS 311 plugin](https://github.com/krasserm/grails-jaxrs). I use it with Jersey.

My application is running on a tomcat 7.0.55 server. My server logs in production show the following info messages. I was wondering why "Couldn't find grammar element for class" is an INFO log. Here is the log:

```
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.NotificationDtoCollection
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.UserDto
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.ItemDtoCollection
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.UploadItemDto
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.UploadItemDto
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.ItemDetailsDto
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class test.shared.dto.ItemDetailsDto
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class boolean
Sep 09, 2014 3:01:03 AM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator attachTypes
```

I found the following questions but they do not help in my case: [Jersey: what does "couldn't find grammar element" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767973/jersey-what-does-couldnt-find-grammar-element-mean) and [A JSON object in a POST request for webserver with JERSEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247110/a-json-object-in-a-post-request-for-webserver-with-jersey)

All my classes have a public default constructor and may be a second parameterized constructor:

```
class UserDto {

    String id
    String firstName
    String lastName

  public UserDto() { }

  public UserDto(User user, User currentUser) {
    ... 
  }

}
```

**What do these INFO log messages mean and how can I prevent them?**

Answer (score 1):

Those messages will go away if you setup the following parameter in your  `web.xml` inside the definition of your `<servlet>`:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And restart your serlvet container to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you use JAXB annotations for your classes? Perhaps you can use this as tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Comment: Could you please post an example for that?

Comment: Why do you recommend JAXB?

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/server/wadl/generators/AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator.html

says:

_This WadlGenerator generates a grammar based on the referenced elements. This is a template class designed to be overridden by specific implementations, for example XML Schema and JSON Schema_ .

I have a feeling that it could help. JAXB is for XML and perhaps it fixes the grammar problem. But I'm not sure.